# How to play sound through only one side on my headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, headset

I have an **Asus STRIX DSP Headset**, and now the cable is broken. I am trying to tape it so the sound is in both ears, but this is pretty much impossible if I can't know if the left ear is playing sound or not.

So what I need to do is turn off all sound in the right ear. I get it to turn off, but then when the left ear disconnects it activates sound in the right ear again.

How can I stop the sound in the right ear to activate again?

Answer (score 6):

I confirmed that ***this works with headphones on Windows 10***.

> ### [How To Adjust Audio Balance (Left – Right) In Windows 10](http://sodeve.net/2015/09/how-to-adjust-audio-balance-left-right-in-windows-10/comment-page-1/)
>
> 1. Right ***click*** on the ***Volume Icon*** in the ***System Tray***. It will pop up something like below.
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Click ***Sounds***. A new window will pop up like below
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Click ***Playback*** tab.
>
> [image]
>
> Once above window show up, select the *active device*, then click ***Properties***.
>
> 4. Now the *Speaker’s window* will pop like below.
>
> [image]
>
> Click the ***Levels*** tab.
>
> 5. In the Levels tab, click the ***Balance*** button, as shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> 6. Now the *Balance window* will pop up.
>
> [image]
>
> With this we can now adjust the balance between left and right
>   speaker. The best way to adjust is while listening to music. This way
>   we know immediately the best balance setting for the headphones.
>
> <sub>[source](http://sodeve.net/2015/09/how-to-adjust-audio-balance-left-right-in-windows-10/comment-page-1/)</sub>

Comment: You just helped me a lot to repair my headphones.

Comment: On Windows 10 1903, clicking on the volume icon in the system tray no longer opens the mentioned Sound window, to open it you would need **Change system sound** in Control Panel.

Comment: @BorislavIvanov I just added an answer for the Windows 10 1903 version that I confirmed does this same thing. Check it out when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed that **this works with headphones on Windows 10 version 1903.**

> ### Control Right and Left Headset Balance Windows 10
>
> 1. From the lower right hand side system tray, right **click** on the **Volume Control** icon
>
>    [image]
> 2. **Click** on the **Open Sound settings** option
>
>    [image]
> 3. **Click** on the **Device properties** option
>
>    [image]
> 4. Now **adjust the Left or Right balance as-needed** then close that window
>
>    [image]
> 5. To test a**djust the Volume Control up and down** to confirm all works as expected
>
>    [image]